# How to disable Properties and Personal Information from being stored for any file?

Tags: windows-7, personal-data

Is there some way to permanently disable that "feature" completely for all file types when the files are saved?

It's a hassle having to check each file before sending it to someone, and the way to remove it (Properties->Details->Click Link->Make copy of file, delete original file) is so cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data streams that Windows may add to NTFS files may be erased by using the utility [streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440) by Mark Russinovich :

```
streams -d <file>
```

However, many other file-types contain meta-data, and especially Office documents and images. These have to be deleted by applications specialized per file-type.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent those streams from ever being created ?

Comment: These data streams are created by programs, normally not by Windows itself. They are quite rare, and each program must be treated separately. Which kinds of files do you have problems with?

Comment: Well, all files. I just don't want any so-called personal-information in the properties of any file.

Comment: Very few programs create data streams, so they are not a problem. Images and documents are a problem, and for some of them there are programs that say they delete all info. However, even experts were sometimes caught leaking personal info in images and documents. To really be sure of a file being anonymous, you can use a hex editor to search the file for your info. But you may not know what to search for.